# Not in index, seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import svm

data1 = pd.read_csv("D:/MLS_Machine_Learning_Supervised/M_F.csv")

print(data1.shape)
print(data1.head())

sns.lmplot("Weight","Height", data = data1)
```

I have just started with machine learning, I was trying out the `svm model` but before that, I wanted to plot and visualize data using `scatter plot`, for this, I created a custom `CSV` file using *WPS spreadsheet* with 30 rows and 3 columns, With one of the columns named as *Height*, but after executing the code it gives me an error,

```
    (30, 3)
   Height   Weight Class
0      168      68  Male
1      172      75  Male
2      177      80  Male
3      177      81  Male
4      179      82  Male
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\MLS_Machine_Learning_Supervised\new_copy - Copy.py", line 27, in <module>
    sns.lmplot("Weight","Height", data = data1)
  File "C:\Users\SYSMGR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\seaborn\regression.py", line 551, in lmplot
    data = data[cols]
  File "C:\Users\SYSMGR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2934, in __getitem__
    raise_missing=True)
  File "C:\Users\SYSMGR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1354, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
  File "C:\Users\SYSMGR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1161, in _get_listlike_indexer
    raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "C:\Users\SYSMGR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1252, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))
KeyError: "['Height'] not in index"
```

I am not able to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sns.lmplot(x= "Weight",y="Height", data = data1)
```

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an actual answer? Maybe add some detail about why naming the parameters is important or mention at all that it is the difference.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.